# On/in/at in regards to lines of a program

Tags: prepositions, in-on-at

Say I have a program that swaps two variables:

```
1)read a
2)read b
3)buf=a
4)a=b
5)b=buf
6)print a
7)print b
```

I want to say that I swap the values of a and b ***on*** (or should it be ***at*** or ***in***?) lines 3-5 of the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would definitely use *on* here. *On* is the preposition we tend to use when referring to written things in these contexts. For example:

> Open your books and read the text **on** page 27.
>
> On this page, read the sentence *on* line 5.

This carries over to your situation:

> The values are swapped on lines 3-5.

The code appears *on* those lines. If you were referring to the actual execution of the program instead of the written text of it, you might instead say something like

> The values are swapped when lines 3-5 are executed.

But I think *swapped on* works just fine.

Comment: Note that we'd say "see the text on page 27" and "see listing 27.1", but not "See the code *on* listing 27.1, " right ?

Comment: I agree that your examples are all good English, but I think there might be a little room for personal variation here.  I think that, depending on how I'm thinking of it, I might say (for example) *"The values are swapped* ***in*** *lines 3-5."*  (For what it's worth, I too am a native speaker, and I've been a programmer all my life.)

Comment: @snailboat Oh! The question was edited to ask if *in* was appropriate after I first read it; I only noticed *on vs at*. You're quite right, *in* could work as well. Silly of me to not notice the edit!

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you really mean. As a programmer myself, I see you're doing the temp swap. So the correct coding answer would be:

> Swap the values at lines 3 - 5

Better would be:

> Swap the value a with b, as shown on lines 3 through 5.

This is the same as

> Swap the values (like they are shown) *at* lines 3 through 5.

Comment: I disagree with use of *at* with more than one line number at a time.  Of the offered choices, *in* is most correct; however, it would be better to do it without a preposition: "Lines 3-5 swap the two values".

Comment: yes, your rendition "Lines 3-5 swap the two..." is even better, unless you need to emphasize a and b for some context reason.  Yes, I've seen "in" used a fair amount in textbooks too, but "at" lines 3-5 is also common, and not incorrect because it refers to a *block* of lines as one unit, e.g. the code is folded at lines 20-30, which is a shortened version of "code is folded [starting] at lines ...".  So I propose my rendition is correct as it would fully read: "The swap of values starts *at* line 3 and goes through line 5." Since it's really only 3 lines, such a longer version is verbose.

Comment: @ jwpat7 consider also the common idiom: "See the xyz code *in* listing 4.1" which is an entire block of code. Then the author might drill down into specifics: "In listing 4.1, the routine *at* lines 10 - 20 show how xyz does..."   So In Listing at line(s).   In Lines would not work well there.  This probably comes from *something being at an address* as opposed to *something being in an address* @iensen - I hope it's now more obvious that all three of these work, in/on/at, but it's more a style question. You could also say, as jwpat7 suggests, "Swap the values [shown] in lines 3-5." (cont...)

Comment: (...) the important thing is to be consistent. If it's really important, have a native speaker review it if possible.  In any case, we would understand what you mean if you use in/on/at.

Comment: @HowardPautz I'm a programmer and a native speaker as well, and I'd use *on* here, not at. "Open your books and read the text *on* page 27." "On this page, read the sentence *on* line 5." "The values are swapped on lines 3-5."

Comment: @Wendi yup - like my second example. (Now, I'm gonna be watching for this every time I read :))

Comment: I think this is another one of those great examples showing the overlapping functionality of basic prepositions. I see all of these as viable and grammatical: _the values are swapped in lines 3 through 5; the values are swapped at lines 3 and 5; the value are swapped on lines 3 and 5._

Comment: @J.R. yes, well said! It really depends on the perspective you have as the programmer, writer, editor, publisher, and ultimately the reader. Interesting that you picked up on this thread - I asked two of my publisher friends who work in the chop-shop of computer books - they couldn't make up their minds :-P